# Telegram bot api: Send_message_media_invalid

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

My Telegram bot works inline and sends files of different types. I use `InlineQueryResultCachedDocument` for it. Most of the time it works correctly, but if I'm trying to send `*.html` files it drops 
`BadRequest: Send_message_media_invalid`

#### Why does this happen?

---

My request:

```
{
  'inline_query_id': '<QUERY_ID>', 
  'results': '[
    {
      "id": "<RESULT ID>", 
      "title": "text", 
      "document_file_id": "<FILE ID>", 
      "description": "", 
      "caption": "", 
      "parse_mode": "html", 
      "type": "document"
    }
  ]', 
'cache_time': 1, 
'is_personal': True
}
```

My response:

```
{
  "ok":false,
  "error_code":400,
  "description":"Bad Request: SEND_MESSAGE_MEDIA_INVALID"
}
```

Is there a list of prohibited files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `.PDF` and `.ZIP` files are supported.

The [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequeryresultdocument) says:

> *InlineQueryResultDocument*
>
> Represents a link to a file. By default, this file will be sent by the user with an optional caption. Alternatively, you can use input_message_content to send a message with the specified content instead of the file. Currently, only **.PDF** and **.ZIP** files can be sent using this method.